# 'sorry some error occurred' while integrating PayUMoney payment gateway in Test mode

Tags: php, integration, payment-gateway, payu, payumoney

I'm trying to integrate **PayUMoney** payment gateway in my client site. My client provided me the login details of **PayUMoney**. I was able to locate the **Merchant Key** but cannot find either of the two:

1. Merchant Salt
2. Developer site where I can create a test account and test on sandbox

**PayUMoney** provided me a form with some default value but when I test, it gives the message: sorry some error occurred.

Here is the form:

```
<?php
// Merchant key here as provided by Payu
$MERCHANT_KEY = "JBZaLc";

// Merchant Salt as provided by Payu
$SALT = "GQs7yium";

// End point - change to https://secure.payu.in for LIVE mode
$PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://test.payu.in";

$action = '';

$posted = array();
if(!empty($_POST)) {
//print_r($_POST);
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {    
$posted[$key] = $value; 

}
}

$formError = 0;

if(empty($posted['txnid'])) {
// Generate random transaction id
$txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);
} else {
$txnid = $posted['txnid'];
}
$hash = '';
// Hash Sequence
$hashSequence =     "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";
if(empty($posted['hash']) && sizeof($posted) > 0) {
if(
      empty($posted['key'])
      || empty($posted['txnid'])
      || empty($posted['amount'])
      || empty($posted['firstname'])
      || empty($posted['email'])
      || empty($posted['phone'])
      || empty($posted['productinfo'])
      || empty($posted['surl'])
      || empty($posted['furl'])
      || empty($posted['service_provider'])
) {
$formError = 1;
} else {
//$posted['productinfo'] = json_encode(json_decode('[{"name":"tutionfee","description":"","value":"500","isRequired":"false"},{"name":"developmentfee","description":"monthly tution     fee","value":"1500","isRequired":"false"}]'));
$hashVarsSeq = explode('|', $hashSequence);
$hash_string = '';  
foreach($hashVarsSeq as $hash_var) {
  $hash_string .= isset($posted[$hash_var]) ? $posted[$hash_var] : '';
  $hash_string .= '|';
}

$hash_string .= $SALT;


$hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hash_string));
$action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';
}
} elseif(!empty($posted['hash'])) {
$hash = $posted['hash'];
$action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var hash = '<?php echo $hash ?>';
function submitPayuForm() {
  if(hash == '') {
    return;
  }
  var payuForm = document.forms.payuForm;
  payuForm.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="submitPayuForm()">
<h2>PayU Form</h2>
<br/>
<?php if($formError) { ?>
  <span style="color:red">Please fill all mandatory fields.</span>
  <br/>
  <br/>
<?php } ?>
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" name="payuForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $MERCHANT_KEY ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $hash ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $txnid ?>" />
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Mandatory Parameters</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Amount: </td>
      <td><input name="amount" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['amount'])) ? '' : $posted['amount'] ?>" /></td>
      <td>First Name: </td>
      <td><input name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['firstname'])) ? '' : $posted['firstname']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email: </td>
      <td><input name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['email'])) ? '' : $posted['email']; ?>" /></td>
      <td>Phone: </td>
      <td><input name="phone" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['phone'])) ? '' : $posted['phone']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Info: </td>
      <td colspan="3"><textarea name="productinfo"><?php echo (empty($posted['productinfo'])) ? '' : $posted['productinfo'] ?></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Success URI: </td>
      <td colspan="3"><input name="surl" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['surl'])) ? '' : $posted['surl'] ?>" size="64" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Failure URI: </td>
      <td colspan="3"><input name="furl" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['furl'])) ?     '' : $posted['furl'] ?>" size="64" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Service Provider: </td>
      <td colspan="3"><input name="service_provider" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['service_provider'])) ? '' : $posted['service_provider'] ?>" size="64" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><b>Optional Parameters</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name: </td>
      <td><input name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['lastname'])) ? '' : $posted['lastname']; ?>" /></td>
      <td>Cancel URI: </td>
      <td><input name="curl" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address1: </td>
      <td><input name="address1" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['address1'])) ? '' : $posted['address1']; ?>" /></td>
      <td>Address2: </td>
      <td><input name="address2" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['address2'])) ? '' : $posted['address2']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City: </td>
      <td><input name="city" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['city'])) ? '' : $posted['city']; ?>" /></td>
      <td>State: </td>
      <td><input name="state" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['state'])) ? '' : $posted['state']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Country: </td>
      <td><input name="country" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['country'])) ? '' : $posted['country']; ?>" /></td>
      <td>Zipcode: </td>
      <td><input name="zipcode" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['zipcode'])) ? '' : $posted['zipcode']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UDF1: </td>
      <td><input name="udf1" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['udf1'])) ? '' : $posted['udf1']; ?>" /></td>
      <td>UDF2: </td>
      <td><input name="udf2" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['udf2'])) ? '' : $posted['udf2']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UDF3: </td>
      <td><input name="udf3" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['udf3'])) ? '' : $posted['udf3']; ?>" /></td>
      <td>UDF4: </td>
      <td><input name="udf4" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['udf4'])) ? '' : $posted['udf4']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UDF5: </td>
      <td><input name="udf5" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['udf5'])) ? '' : $posted['udf5']; ?>" /></td>
      <td>PG: </td>
      <td><input name="pg" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['pg'])) ? '' : $posted['pg']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <?php if(!$hash) { ?>
        <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
      <?php } ?>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After logging in payumoney at the bottom click on the tab "Download PayUMoney integration kit" . You will see PHP download .After downloading it just refer to the pdf , in that pdf u will get the test details(like credit card number,password,expiry date,etc) and other details also. But as you said i am also getting the same problem message when i am using their code . 
Did you get any solution yet ?

Comment: Contact payumoney support and provide your company details, They will provide you the test account... The provided key and salt will not work..

Comment: For testing accounts, we don't have to provide the 'service_provider' field. I removed it and it worked!

Comment: @Ashutosh I am getting a similar problem. I tried to test your code after removing the service provider field but it still doesn't work. Probably I'm doing something wrong. Could you help me and tell me exactly what portion of your code needs to be changed? Thanks.

Comment: @Ashutosh How did you activate the account? I am also facing this issue for 5 days.

Comment: You need to call them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I came to know that they have not activated the test account.

Comment: Do you mean this error occurs if test account is not active? So, Is it required to ask PayU team for the same?

Comment: Yes, I need to contact them to confirm. After that, it was working. Also make sure you are using test key for testing

Comment: Thank you for reply Ashutosh. Can you please have a look on my question & comment it over there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046696/how-to-integrate-test-payu-payment-gateway-in-android-application

Comment: Can you please tell me why it asks me every time for LOGIN on PayUMoney web page?

Comment: It is  their way of working. I also was in your state when I saw for the first time :) . You can directly go ahead and pick credit / debit card.

Comment: But without login I can't move to Credit/Debit card screen. Can you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 32):

This is confusing for the first timers. Supplied default `key` and `salt` will not work straight away.

In order to test the gateway using a test key and salt, kindly follow these steps:

> 1. Go on test.payumoney.com
> 2. Sign up as a merchant - use any of
>      your valid email ids - kindly do not use a random email id.
> 3. Complete the "Business Details" - you may use PAN no. ABCDE1234F and
>      DOB - 01/04/1990
> 4. Complete "Bank Account Details" (You may use
>      IFSC- ALLA0212632)
> 5. You dont have to worry about Bank verification step or any other step after that.
> 6. Go to below mentioned location to get the Test
>      Merchant Id : Seller Dashboard -> Settings -> My account -> Profile
>      Settings
> 7. After that send your test merchant id to technical team using [contact us](https://test.payumoney.com/contactus.html) form and they will approve.
> 8. Once approved you can find your test key and salt at : Seller Dashboard -> Settings -> My account -> Merchant Key - Salt.
> 9. Replace default `key` and `salt` with newly generated test `key` and `salt`. After this you should not see error, **Sorry, Some Problem Occurred.**

I hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with pinkal, this is so confusing

Comment: Indian payment gateways are all very confusing and cumbersome.

Comment: I went through the same issue. They has now changed process of sharing test credentials. Thus, I created an account at https://test.payumoney.com and write to the technical team of payumoney. Then my account was approved. I followed up them through email and call. After approval, I can get MerchantId, MerchantKey and Merchant salt from Seller Dashboard->MyAccount

Comment: Any ideas about test credit/debit cards? How do i get that? What all do PayUMoney support?

Comment: @activatedgeek I don'y know if this still works but try , Test Card Name: any name
Test Card Number: 5123456789012346
Test CVV: 123
Test Expiry: May 2017

Comment: @pinkalvansia That works! Thanks :). I've updated the answer with these details.

Comment: @pinkalvansia Hey Hi, While configuring merchant account its asking for Allahabad bank account number. What it should be?

Comment: @pinkal vansia great answer. Thanks :)

Comment: 2017, it now needs a valid PAN number, even for test account. Good job PayU.

Comment: @KaranKumar how is it a good job? In order to test and build the system you have to get approved. And it takes several days to get approved. This is even worse!

Comment: @SlickSlime that was sarcasm :/

Answer (score 13):

The Key and salt provided by payumoney is invalid use the following for testing:

```
// Merchant key here as provided by Payu
$MERCHANT_KEY = "gtKFFx";

// Merchant Salt as provided by Payu
$SALT = "eCwWELxi";
```

And make sure to leave service provider field blank.

Comment: Same result **Sorry, Some Problem Occurred.**

Comment: Leaving the service provider name blank worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: And make sure to leave service provider field blank.

Comment: I got it working with salt = "wia56q6O"

Answer (score 9):

There is a field "Service Provider"in the form (param name is - service_provider). The value of this field should be 'payu_paisa'. If you fill anything else in this field in the form, you will get an error.

Comment: hello tech support? did you get it working for PayU india for IOS?

Comment: Why such a hilarious code integration in php? is there any good readable code out there?

Comment: i have already added "payu_paisa" but still error with test USer

Comment: @techsupport PayUMoney : I am getting Command name not found . I am trying to integrate payU with android

Comment: @techsupport PayUMoney  After the integration with testing url , after entering card its displaying `Invalid Transaction. Please try again` in success.php . Y hash code is not generating ?

Answer (score 9):

Leave the Service Provider field as blank. 
That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Returns the pay page url or the merchant js file.
 * 
 * @param unknown $params           
 * @param unknown $salt         
 * @throws Exception
 * @return Ambigous <multitype:number string , multitype:number Ambigous <boolean, string> >
 */
function pay ( $params, $salt )
{
    if ( ! is_array( $params ) ) throw new Exception( 'Pay params is empty' );

    if ( empty( $salt ) ) throw new Exception( 'Salt is empty' );

    $payment = new Payment( $salt );
    $result = $payment->pay( $params );
    unset( $payment );

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Displays the pay page.
 * 
 * @param unknown $params           
 * @param unknown $salt         
 * @throws Exception
 */
function pay_page ( $params, $salt )
{
    if ( count( $_POST ) && isset( $_POST['mihpayid'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['mihpayid'] ) ) {
        $_POST['surl'] = $params['surl'];
        $_POST['furl'] = $params['furl'];

        $result = response( $_POST, $salt );
        Misc::show_reponse( $result );
    } else {
        $host = (isset( $_SERVER['https'] ) ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        if ( isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) && ! empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) $params['surl'] = $host;
        if ( isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) && ! empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) $params['furl'] = $host;

        $result = pay( $params, $salt );
        Misc::show_page( $result );
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the response object.
 * 
 * @param unknown $params           
 * @param unknown $salt         
 * @throws Exception
 * @return number
 */
function response ( $params, $salt )
{
    if ( ! is_array( $params ) ) throw new Exception( 'PayU response params is empty' );

    if ( empty( $salt ) ) throw new Exception( 'Salt is empty' );

    if ( empty( $params['status'] ) ) throw new Exception( 'Status is empty' );

    $response = new Response( $salt );
    $result = $response->get_response( $_POST );
    unset( $response );

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Basic autoloader
 * 
 * @param classname $file           
 *
define( 'INCLUDE_PATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/src/' );
function __autoload ( $file )
{
    require_once INCLUDE_PATH . $file . '.php';
}
*/

/* Should libcurl or curl.so be absent. */

if ( ! function_exists( 'curl_init' ) ) :

    define( 'CURLOPT_URL', 1 );
    define( 'CURLOPT_USERAGENT', 2 );
    define( 'CURLOPT_POST', 3 );
    define( 'CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS', 4 );
    define( 'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER', 5 );
    define( 'CURLOPT_REFERER', 6 );
    define( 'CURLOPT_HEADER', 7 );
    define( 'CURLOPT_TIMEOUT', 8 );
    define( 'CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT', 9 );
    define( 'CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION', 10 );
    define( 'CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER', 11 );
    define( 'CURLOPT_PROXY', 12 );
    define( 'CURLOPT_PORT', 13 );
    define( 'CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER', 14 );
    define( 'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST', 15 );
    define( 'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER', 16 );

    function curl_init ( $url = false )
    {
        return new Curl( $url );
    }

    function curl_setopt ( &$ch, $name, $value )
    {
        $ch->setopt( $name, $value );
    }

    function curl_exec ( $ch )
    {
        return $ch->exec();
    }

    function curl_close ( &$ch )
    {
        unset( $ch );
    }

    function curl_errno ( $ch )
    {
        return $ch->error;
    }

    function curl_error ( $ch_error )
    {
        return "Could not open socket";
    }

    function curl_getinfo ( $ch, $opt = NULL )
    {
        return $ch->info;
    }

    function curl_setopt_array ( &$ch, $opt )
    {
        $ch->setoptArray( $opt );
    }



endif;


class Curl {
    private $url = "";
    private $user_agent = "libCurl";
    private $return_result = false;
    private $referrer = false;
    private $cookies_on = false;
    private $proxy = array ();
    private $timeout = 30;
    private $cookies;
    private $headers;
    private $method = "GET";
    private $httpHeader = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    public $error = 0;
    public $info = array ();

    function __construct ( $url = false )
    {
        $this->cookies = new Cookies();
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->info['total_time'] = time();
    }

    function __destruct ()
    {}

    private function getHost ( $url )
    {
        $url = str_replace( array ( "http://", "https://" ), "", $url );
        $tmp = explode( "/", $url );
        return $tmp[0];
    }

    private function getQuery ( $url )
    {
        $url = str_replace( array ( "http://", "https://" ), "", $url );
        $tmp = explode( "/", $url, 2 );
        return "/" . $tmp[1];
    }

    private function _parseRawData ( $rawData )
    {
        $array = explode( "\r\n\r\n", $rawData, 2 );
        $this->header_data = $array[0];
        $this->content = $array[1];
        $this->_parseHeaders( $array[0] );
    }

    private function _parseHeaders ( $rawHeaders )
    {
        $rawHeaders = trim( $rawHeaders );
        $headers = explode( "\r\n", $rawHeaders );

        foreach ( $headers as $header ) {
            if ( preg_match( "|http/1\.. (\d+)|i", $header, $match ) ) {
                $this->status_code = $match[1];
                continue;
            }

            $headerArray = explode( ":", $header );
            $headerName = trim( $headerArray[0] );
            $headerValue = trim( $headerArray[1] );

            if ( preg_match( "|set-cookie2?|i", $headerName ) ) $this->cookies->add( $headerValue );
            if ( isset( $headerName ) ) $this->headers[strtolower( $headerName )] = $headerValue;
        }

        if ( isset( $this->headers["location"] ) ) {
            $this->url = $this->headers["location"];
            $this->exec();
        }
    }

    public function setopt ( $name, $value = false )
    {
        switch ( $name ) {
        case CURLOPT_URL :
            $this->url = $value;
            $this->proxy["port"] = substr( $this->url, 0, 5 ) === 'https' ? 443 : 80;
            break;
        case CURLOPT_USERAGENT :
            $this->user_agent = $value;
            break;
        case CURLOPT_POST :
            $this->method = ($value == true) ? "POST" : "GET";
            break;
        case CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS :
            $this->post_data = $value;
            break;
        case CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER :
            $this->return_result = ($value == true);
            break;
        case CURLOPT_REFERER :
            $this->referrer = $value;
            break;
        case CURLOPT_HEADER :
            $this->options["header"] = ($value == true);
            break;
        case CURLOPT_PROXY :
            list ( $this->proxy["host"], $this->proxy["port"] ) = explode( ":", $value );
            break;
        case CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT : /* Fall through. */
        case CURLOPT_TIMEOUT :
            $this->timeout = ($value >= 0) ? $value : 30;
            break;
        case CURLOPT_PORT :
            $this->proxy["port"] = $value ? $value : (substr( $this->url, 0, 5 ) === 'https' ? 443 : 80);
            break;
        case CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER :
            $this->httpHeader = substr( implode( ";", $value ), 0, - 1 );
            break;
        }
    }

    public function setoptArray ( $options )
    {
        foreach ( $options as $name => $value )
            $this->setopt( $name, $value );
    }

    public function exec ()
    {
        $errno = false;
        $errstr = false;
        $url = $this->url;

        $host = $this->getHost( $url );
        $query = $this->getQuery( $url );

        $this->proxy["host"] = $host;

        if ( isset( $this->proxy["port"] ) ) {
            $this->proxy["host"] = (443 === $this->proxy["port"]) ? "ssl://$host" : $host;
            $fp = pfsockopen( $this->proxy["host"], $this->proxy["port"], $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout );
            $request = $query;
        } else {
            $fp = pfsockopen( $host, 80, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout );
            $request = $query;
        }

        if ( ! $fp ) { /*trigger_error($errstr, E_WARNING);*/ $this->error = 1;
            return;
        }

        $headers = $this->method . " $request HTTP/1.0 \r\nHost: $host \r\n";
        if ( $this->user_agent ) $headers .= "User-Agent: " . $this->user_agent . "\r\n";
        if ( $this->referrer ) $headers .= "Referer: " . $this->referrer . "\r\n";
        if ( $this->method == "POST" ) {
            $headers .= "Content-Type: " . $this->httpHeader . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Length: " . strlen( $this->post_data ) . "\r\n";
        }

        if ( $this->cookies_on ) $headers .= $this->cookies->createHeader();
        $headers .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        if ( "POST" == $this->method ) $headers .= $this->post_data;
        $headers .= "\r\n\r\n";

        fwrite( $fp, $headers );
        $rawData = "";
        while ( ! feof( $fp ) )
            $rawData .= fread( $fp, 512 );
            /* fclose($fp); /* Too lazy to read the docs.*/
        $this->info['total_time'] = time() - $this->info['total_time'];

        $this->_parseRawData( $rawData );
        if ( $this->options["header"] ) $this->content = $rawData;
        if ( $this->return_result ) return $this->content;
        echo $this->content;
    }

}

class Cookies {
    private $cookies;

    function __construct ()
    {}

    function __destruct ()
    {}

    public function add ( $cookie )
    {
        list ( $data, $etc ) = explode( ";", $cookie, 2 );
        list ( $name, $value ) = explode( "=", $data );
        $this->cookies[trim( $name )] = trim( $value );
    }

    public function createHeader ()
    {
        if ( 0 == count( $this->cookies ) || ! is_array( $this->cookies ) ) return "";
        $output = "";
        foreach ( $this->cookies as $name => $value )
            $output .= "$name=$value; ";
        return "Cookies: $output\r\n";
    }

}

class Misc {

    const SUCCESS = 1;
    const FAILURE = 0;

    public static function get_hash ( $params, $salt )
    {
        $posted = array ();

        if ( ! empty( $params ) ) foreach ( $params as $key => $value )
            $posted[$key] = htmlentities( $value, ENT_QUOTES );

        $hash_sequence = "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";

        $hash_vars_seq = explode( '|', $hash_sequence );
        $hash_string = null;

        foreach ( $hash_vars_seq as $hash_var ) {
            $hash_string .= isset( $posted[$hash_var] ) ? $posted[$hash_var] : '';
            $hash_string .= '|';
        }

        $hash_string .= $salt;
        return strtolower( hash( 'sha512', $hash_string ) );
    }

    public static function reverse_hash ( $params, $salt, $status )
    {
        $posted = array ();
        $hash_string = null;

        if ( ! empty( $params ) ) foreach ( $params as $key => $value )
            $posted[$key] = htmlentities( $value, ENT_QUOTES );

        $additional_hash_sequence = 'base_merchantid|base_payuid|miles|additional_charges';
        $hash_vars_seq = explode( '|', $additional_hash_sequence );

        foreach ( $hash_vars_seq as $hash_var )
            $hash_string .= isset( $posted[$hash_var] ) ? $posted[$hash_var] . '|' : '';

        $hash_sequence = "udf10|udf9|udf8|udf7|udf6|udf5|udf4|udf3|udf2|udf1|email|firstname|productinfo|amount|txnid|key";
        $hash_vars_seq = explode( '|', $hash_sequence );
        $hash_string .= $salt . '|' . $status;

        foreach ( $hash_vars_seq as $hash_var ) {
            $hash_string .= '|';
            $hash_string .= isset( $posted[$hash_var] ) ? $posted[$hash_var] : '';
        }

        return strtolower( hash( 'sha512', $hash_string ) );
    }

    public static function curl_call ( $url, $data )
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array( $ch, array ( 
            CURLOPT_URL => $url, 
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data, 
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true, 
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36', 
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0, 
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0 ) );

        $o = curl_exec( $ch );

        if ( curl_errno( $ch ) ) {
            $c_error = curl_error( $ch );

            if ( empty( $c_error ) ) $c_error = 'Server Error';

            return array ( 'curl_status' => Misc::FAILURE, 'error' => $c_error );
        }

        $o = trim( $o );
        return array ( 'curl_status' => Misc::SUCCESS, 'result' => $o );
    }

    public static function show_page ( $result )
    {

        if ( $result['status'] === Misc::SUCCESS )
            header( 'Location:' . $result['data'] );
        else
            throw new Exception( $result['data'] );
    }

    public static function show_reponse ( $result )
    {
        if ( $result['status'] === Misc::SUCCESS )
            $result['data']();
        else
            return $result['data'];
    }

}



class Payment {

    private $url;
    private $salt;
    private $params = array ();

    public function __construct ( $salt, $env = 'test' )
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        switch ( $env ) {
        case 'test' :
            $this->url = 'https://test.payu.in/';
            break;
        case 'prod' :
            $this->url = 'https://secure.payu.in/';
            break;
        default :
            $this->url = 'https://test.payu.in/';
        }
    }

    public function __destruct ()
    {
        unset( $this->url );
        unset( $this->salt );
        unset( $this->params );
    }

    public function __set ( $key, $value )
    {
        $this->params[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __get ( $key )
    {
        return $this->params[$key];
    }

    public function pay ( $params = null )
    {
        if ( is_array( $params ) ) foreach ( $params as $key => $value )
            $this->params[$key] = $value;

        $error = $this->check_params();

        if ( $error === true ) {
            $this->params['hash'] = Misc::get_hash( $this->params, $this->salt );
            $result = Misc::curl_call( $this->url . '_payment?type=merchant_txn', http_build_query( $this->params ) );
            $transaction_id = ($result['curl_status'] === Misc::SUCCESS) ? $result['result'] : null;

            if ( empty( $transaction_id ) ) return array ( 
                'status' => Misc::FAILURE, 
                'data' => $result['error'] );

            return array ( 
                'status' => Misc::SUCCESS, 
                'data' => $this->url . '_payment_options?mihpayid=' . $transaction_id );
        } else {
            return array ( 'status' => Misc::FAILURE, 'data' => $error );
        }
    }

    private function check_params ()
    {
        if ( empty( $this->params['key'] ) ) return $this->error( 'key' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['txnid'] ) ) return $this->error( 'txnid' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['amount'] ) ) return $this->error( 'amount' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['firstname'] ) ) return $this->error( 'firstname' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['email'] ) ) return $this->error( 'email' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['phone'] ) ) return $this->error( 'phone' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['productinfo'] ) ) return $this->error( 'productinfo' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['surl'] ) ) return $this->error( 'surl' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['furl'] ) ) return $this->error( 'furl' );

        return true;
    }

    private function error ( $key )
    {
        return 'Mandatory parameter ' . $key . ' is empty';
    }

}


class Response {

    private $salt;
    private $params = array ();

    public function __construct ( $salt )
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;
    }

    public function __destruct ()
    {
        unset( $this->salt );
        unset( $this->params );
    }

    public function __set ( $key, $value )
    {
        $this->params[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __get ( $key )
    {
        return $this->params[$key];
    }

    public function get_response ( $params = null )
    {
        $this->params = (is_array( $params ) && count( $params )) ? $params : $_POST;

        $error = $this->check_params();

        if ( $error === true ) {
            if ( Misc::reverse_hash( $this->params, $this->salt, $this->params['status'] ) === $this->params['hash'] ) {
                switch ( $this->params['status'] ) {
                case 'success' :
                    return array ( 
                        'status' => Misc::SUCCESS, 
                        'data' => $this->params['surl'] );
                    break;
                case 'failure' :
                    return array ( 
                        'status' => Misc::SUCCESS, 
                        'data' => $this->params['furl'] );
                    break;
                default :
                    return array ( 
                        'status' => Misc::FAILURE, 
                        'data' => 'Unmapped status' );
                }
            } else {
                return array ( 
                    'status' => Misc::FAILURE, 
                    'data' => 'Hash Mismatch' );
            }
        } else {
            return array ( 'status' => Misc::FAILURE, 'data' => $error );
        }

    }

    private function check_params ()
    {
        if ( empty( $this->params['key'] ) ) return $this->error( 'key' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['txnid'] ) ) return $this->error( 'txnid' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['amount'] ) ) return $this->error( 'amount' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['firstname'] ) ) return $this->error( 'firstname' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['email'] ) ) return $this->error( 'email' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['phone'] ) ) return $this->error( 'phone' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['productinfo'] ) ) return $this->error( 'productinfo' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['surl'] ) ) return $this->error( 'surl' );
        if ( empty( $this->params['furl'] ) ) return $this->error( 'furl' );
        return true;
    }

    private function error ( $key )
    {
        return 'Mandatory parameter ' . $key . ' is empty';
    }

}
$txnid = uniqid();
$response = pay_page( array ('key' => 'tradus', 'txnid' => uniqid( 'animesh_' ), 'amount' => rand( 0, 100 ),'firstname' => 'animesh', 'email' => 'animesh.kundu@payu.in', 'phone' => '1234567890','productinfo' => 'This is shit', 'surl' => 'payment_success', 'furl' => 'payment_failure'), '200' );

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It also causes trouble if you are using default form and it asks for `Product Info`. In their PDF document they have given a json format for product info like this -

```js
{“paymentParts”:[{ "name":"abc",
"description":"abcd",
"value":"500",
"isRequired":"true",
“settlementEvent” : “EmailConfirmation” },
{
"name":"xyz",
"description":"wxyz",
"value":"1500",
"isRequired":"false",
“settlementEvent”: “EmailConfirmation” }],
{“paymentIdentifiers”:[{ "field":"CompletionDate",
}, {
"value":"31/10/2012”
"field":"TxnId", "value":"abced"
}]}
```

Inserting this json into the `Product Info` textarea might help you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Payumoney has changed their TEST KEY and TEST SALT

in order to get test mode working use these credentials with test url

```
Test Key - rjQUPktU 
Test Salt - e5iIg1jwi8
```

Still facing problems then try following steps

> Are you using the correct Merchant Key? In many shopping carts, the field name used is "Merchant ID" is used incorrectly in place of Merchant Key. However, what actually needs to be entered is the "Merchant Key" supplied by PayUmoney. Please notice that we send you an email with the following 3 details:
>
> (1) Merchant ID  
>   (2) Merchant Key 
>   (3) Merchant Salt 
>   
>   The Merchant ID sent by PayUmoney is not required in the PayUmoney integration with your website. It is just your registration number with PayUmoney. So, the only 2 information used in the integration are Merchant Key & Merchant Salt.
>   Are you using Test credentials in Live Mode or Live credentials in Test Mode? If yes, please make sure that you use Test credentials in Test Mode and Live credentials in Live Mode. Please make sure that in Test Mode, you are using the below mentioned test credentials only - 
>   Test Key - rjQUPktU 
>   Test Salt - e5iIg1jwi8
>   Have you got all the approvals? 
> If your approvals are pending, it is quite possible that you get this error even though you are doing everything right. Please contact the support team for assistance by scheduling a call using the following link: 
>   https://calendly.com/payumoney-integration/30_minutes

Comment: not working with these key and salt @Rishabh Gusain

Answer (score 0):

Recently, PayUMoney done some modifications in test environment due to which test key-JBZaLc and salt-GQs7yium will not work anymore.

In order to test the gateway using a test key and salt,you have to
Go on test.payumoney.com and Sign up as a merchant .So you will get merchant ID and Salt ID.

Answer (score 0):

For PayU APIs Asp per doc and other references
API refs : https://www.payumoney.com/dev-guide/apireference.html

Initially enable Test mode the can use the Sandbox Url for testing APIs
Test-Mode : https://developer.payumoney.com/test-mode/
Testing APIs in the Test Mode
You can test all the APIs provided by PayUmoney in the Test mode using your test credentials. To test APIs in sandbox add /sandbox at the beginning of the relative URL of the API you are calling and also ensure that you are passing the Test Authorization Header in the API request.

For eg, to test check Merchant Transaction Status API:

The Production URL is

https://www.payumoney.com/payment/payment/chkMerchantTxnStatus

And in Test Mode:

https://www.payumoney.com/sandbox/payment/payment/chkMerchantTxnStatus