# How to integrate TEST PayU Payment Gateway in android application?

Tags: android, android-webview, payment-gateway, payu

I am new in Payment Gateway. Currently, I am working on a mobile app where I need to integrate PayU payment gateway in android app.

So far, I have created a code for TEST url & when I run my app I get below exception:

**`An error occurred. Sorry, some problem occurred.`**

Screenshot of mobile app
[image]

This is my code:

```
public class PayMentGateWay extends Activity {
     private ArrayList<String> post_val = new ArrayList<String>();
     private String post_Data="";
     WebView webView ;
     final Activity activity = this;
     private String tag = "PayMentGateWay";
     private String hash,hashSequence;

     String merchant_key="JBZaLc";
        String salt="GQs7yium";
        String action1 ="";
        String base_url="https://test.payu.in";
        int error=0;
        String hashString="";
        Map<String,String> params;
        String txnid ="";

        Handler mHandler = new Handler();


    @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
         getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        webView = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webView);

        post_val.add("key");
        post_val.add("JBZaLc");
        post_val.add("txnid");
        post_val.add("5d59dae66618a14f5020");
        post_val.add("amount");
        post_val.add("100.00");
        post_val.add("productinfo");

        post_val.add("{paymentParts:[{name:abc,description:abcd,value:500,isRequired:true,settlementEvent:EmailConfirmation}], paymentIdentifiers:[{field:CompletionDate, value:25/06/2015}]}");
        post_val.add("firstname");
        post_val.add("pqrs");
        post_val.add("email");
        post_val.add("xxxx@xxxmail.com");
        post_val.add("phone");
        post_val.add("xxxxxxxxxx");
        post_val.add("surl");
        post_val.add("https://www.google.com");
        post_val.add("furl");
        post_val.add("https://www.gmail.com");
        post_val.add("hash");
        post_val.add("");
        post_val.add("provider");
        post_val.add("payu_paisa");
        Log.d(tag, "post_val: "+post_val);
        params= new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(int i = 0;i<post_val.size();){
            params.put(post_val.get(i), post_val.get(i+1));

            i+=2;   
        }

        if(empty(params.get("txnid"))){
            Random rand = new Random();
            String rndm = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt())+(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
            txnid=hashCal("SHA-256",rndm).substring(0,20);
            popup("txnid : " + txnid);
            System.out.println("......txnid...... " + txnid);
        } else {
            txnid=params.get("txnid");
            System.out.println("....else.......txnid...... " + txnid);
        }

            //String udf2 = txnid;
        String txn="abcd";
         hash="";
        String hashSequence = "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";
        if(empty(params.get("hash")) && params.size()>0) {
            if( empty(params.get("key"))
                || empty(params.get("txnid"))
                || empty(params.get("amount"))
                || empty(params.get("firstname"))
                || empty(params.get("email"))
                || empty(params.get("phone"))
                || empty(params.get("productinfo"))
                || empty(params.get("surl"))
                || empty(params.get("furl"))
                || empty(params.get("service_provider"))

        ) {
                String[] hashVarSeq = hashSequence.split("\\|");
                for (int i = 0; i < hashVarSeq.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("<<<<<>>>>>>>> " + hashVarSeq[i]);
                }

                for(String part : hashVarSeq)
                {
                    hashString= (empty(params.get(part))) ? hashString.concat("") : hashString.concat(params.get(part));
                    hashString=hashString.concat("|");
                    System.out.println("??????? " + hashString);
                }
                hashString=hashString.concat(salt);


                 hash=hashCal("SHA-512",hashString);
                 System.out.println(hashString + " /////~~~~~~ " + hash);
                action1=base_url.concat("/_payment");
            }
        }
        else if(!empty(params.get("hash")))
        {
            hash=params.get("hash");
            action1=base_url.concat("/_payment");
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!HASHHHHHHH!!!!!! " + hash);
        }

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){


            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>onReceivedError>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                    SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>onReceivedSslError>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
                Toast.makeText(activity, "SslError! " +  error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 handler.proceed();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>shouldOverrideUrlLoading>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>onPageFinished>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
            }


        });


        webView.setVisibility(0);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);

        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new PayUJavaScriptInterface(activity), "PayUMoney");
        Map<String, String> mapParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mapParams.put("key",merchant_key);
        mapParams.put("hash",PayMentGateWay.this.hash);
        mapParams.put("txnid",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("txnid"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("txnid"));
        Log.d(tag, "txnid: "+PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("txnid"));
        mapParams.put("service_provider","payu_paisa");

            mapParams.put("amount",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("amount"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("amount"));
            mapParams.put("firstname",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("firstname"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("firstname"));
            mapParams.put("email",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("email"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("email"));
            mapParams.put("phone",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("phone"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("phone"));

            mapParams.put("productinfo",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("productinfo"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("productinfo"));
            mapParams.put("surl",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("surl"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("surl"));
            mapParams.put("furl",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("furl"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("furl"));
            mapParams.put("lastname",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("lastname"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("lastname"));

            mapParams.put("address1",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("address1"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("address1"));
            mapParams.put("address2",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("address2"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("address2"));
            mapParams.put("city",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("city"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("city"));
            mapParams.put("state",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("state"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("state"));

            mapParams.put("country",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("country"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("country"));
            mapParams.put("zipcode",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("zipcode"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("zipcode"));
            mapParams.put("udf1",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf1"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf1"));
            mapParams.put("udf2",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf2"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf2"));

            mapParams.put("udf3",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf3"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf3"));
            mapParams.put("udf4",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf4"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf4"));
            mapParams.put("udf5",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf5"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf5"));
            mapParams.put("pg",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("pg"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("pg"));
            webview_ClientPost(webView, action1, mapParams.entrySet());

    }
    public class PayUJavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        PayUJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }


        public void success(long id, final String paymentId) {

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

        mHandler = null;

        Intent intent = new Intent(PayMentGateWay.this, MainActivity.class);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        intent.putExtra("result", "success");

        intent.putExtra("paymentId", paymentId);

        startActivity(intent);

        finish();

        }

        });

        }

    }
     public void webview_ClientPost(WebView webView, String url, Collection< Map.Entry<String, String>> postData){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.append("<html><head></head>");
            sb.append("<body onload='form1.submit()'>");
            sb.append(String.format("<form id='form1' action='%s' method='%s'>", url, "post"));
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : postData) {
                sb.append(String.format("<input name='%s' type='hidden' value='%s' />", item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
            }
            sb.append("</form></body></html>");
            Log.d(tag, "webview_ClientPost called");
           webView.loadData(sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
     }


     public void success(long id, final String paymentId) {

     mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {

     mHandler = null;

     Intent intent = new Intent(PayMentGateWay.this, MainActivity.class);

     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

     intent.putExtra(Constants.ACCOUNT_NAME, "success");

     intent.putExtra(Constants._ID, paymentId);

     startActivity(intent);

     finish();

     }

     });

     }


    public boolean empty(String s)
    {
        if(s== null || s.trim().equals(""))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public String hashCal(String type,String str){
        byte[] hashseq=str.getBytes();
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        try{
        MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
        algorithm.reset();
        algorithm.update(hashseq);
        byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();



        for (int i=0;i<messageDigest.length;i++) {
            String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append("0");
            hexString.append(hex);
        }

        }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae){ }

        return hexString.toString();


    }

    public void popup(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(PayMentGateWay.this, "" + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

I really don't know what is the exact problem. Why I am not able to see the next page or am I missing something?

Comment: what is success method?

Comment: It should be called explicitly as payment is done successfully.

Comment: could u share the full code for integration of pay u money?

Comment: Hi, Could you please share your working code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was happened due to technical error at PayUMoney. Needed to contact support team to issue new Merchant ID & Key.

Comment: I already told you this,instead of accepting my answer you copied and accepted your answer only.

Comment: Hey @Spartan: Could you please your complete code which is working,.

Answer (score 6):

I think your code is okay, I am also doing same and got to know from payu that **test** **merchant_key** and **salt** is not working currently. Try for production mode.

If you want to load data from server use(postUrl):

```
 post_Data = "hash="+PayMentGateWay.this.hash+"&key="+merchant_key+"&txnid="+PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("txnid")+"&amount="+PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("amount")+
                "&productinfo="+PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("productinfo")+"&firstname="+PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("firstname")+
                "&email="+PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("email")+"&phone="+PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("phone")+
                "&surl="+PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("surl")+"&furl="+ PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("furl")+
                "&service_provider="+ "payu_paisa";

 webView.postUrl("https://secure.payu.in/_payment", EncodingUtils.getBytes(post_Data, "base64"));
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Are you able to see the PayUMoney web page?

Comment: Yesterday I was getting same problem for my website for test mode but in production mode it worked.

Comment: No no. I am asking you do you get PayUMoney Login Page or it asks you directly for Payment details

Comment: It takes me to PayUMoney Login page.

Comment: Use `webview.postUrl();`  instead of  `webview.loadData();` if you are not able to load data in web view.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to make those changes in my code? How to pass byte array instead of string data?

Comment: I checked your code and it is working nicely in `postUrl` and do not use `postData()` if you want to load data from network. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Okay. I just want to ask is Sign Up/Sign In web page mandatory in PayUMoney? Can I skip this page?

Comment: not mandatory(you can skip)... please accept answer if you got the solution, Thanks.

Comment: Do I need salt key in production/live mode?

Comment: Yes, to generate checksum we need salt key.

Comment: @spartan, where i need to call this class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345519/payment-processing-integration-android

Comment: Hi @VVB: Could you please share your working code pls ?

Comment: @ManoharPerepa this is working perfectly http://stackoverflow.com/a/32347303/3863689

Comment: Success method is never being called

Answer (score 5):

I have successfully implemented payment Gateway.

*Images used in drawable for progress dialog*
[image: l_icon]
[image: l_icon]
[image: l_icon]
[image: l_icon]

**PayUMoneyActivity**

```
public class PayUMoneyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;
Context activity;
/**
 * Order Id
 * To Request for Updating Payment Status if Payment Successfully Done
 */
int mId;
private String mMerchantKey = "JBZaLc";//For merchant and salt key you need to contact payu money tech support otherwise you get error
private String mSalt = "GQs7yium";//copy and paste works fine 
private String mBaseURL = "https://test.payu.in";
private String mAction = ""; // For Final URL
private String mTXNId; // This will create below randomly
private String mHash; // This will create below randomly
private String mProductInfo; // From Previous Activity
private String mFirstName; // From Previous Activity
private String mEmailId; // From Previous Activity
private double mAmount; // From Previous Activity
private String mPhone; // From Previous Activity
private String mServiceProvider = "payu_paisa";
private String mSuccessUrl = "https://payu.herokuapp.com/success";
private String mFailedUrl = "https://payu.herokuapp.com/failure";


boolean isFromOrder;
/**
 * Handler os handler
 */
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private String TAG = "User info";
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


/**
 * @param savedInstanceState
 */
@SuppressLint({"AddJavascriptInterface", "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "JavascriptInterface"})
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   /**
     * Setting WebView to Screen
     */
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_payumoney);
    /**
     * start processing Payu dialog
     */
    progressBarVisibilityPayuChrome(View.VISIBLE);

    /**
     * Creating WebView
     */
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.payumoney_webview);

    /**
     * Context Variable
     */
    activity = getApplicationContext();
    /**
     * Getting Intent Variables...
     */
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        mFirstName = bundle.getString("name");
        mEmailId = bundle.getString("email");
        mProductInfo = bundle.getString("productInfo");
        mAmount = Double.parseDouble(bundle.getString("amount"));//in my case amount getting as String so i parse it double
        mPhone = bundle.getString("phone");
        mId = bundle.getInt("id");
        isFromOrder = bundle.getBoolean("isFromOrder");

        Log.i(TAG, "" + mFirstName + " : " + mEmailId + " : " + mAmount + " : " + mPhone);

        /**
         * Creating Transaction Id
         */
        Random rand = new Random();
        String randomString = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt()) + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
        mTXNId = hashCal("SHA-256", randomString).substring(0, 20);

        mAmount = new BigDecimal(mAmount).setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP).intValue();

        /**
         * Creating Hash Key
         */
        mHash = hashCal("SHA-512", mMerchantKey + "|" +
                mTXNId + "|" +
                mAmount + "|" +
                mProductInfo + "|" +
                mFirstName + "|" +
                mEmailId + "|||||||||||" +
                mSalt);

        /**
         * Final Action URL...
         */
        mAction = mBaseURL.concat("/_payment");

        /**
         * WebView Client
         */
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                                           SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "SSL Error! " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                handler.proceed();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                if (url.equals(mSuccessUrl)) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, PaymentStatusActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("status", true);
                    intent.putExtra("transaction_id", mTXNId);
                    intent.putExtra("id", mId);
                    intent.putExtra("isFromOrder", isFromOrder);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (url.equals(mFailedUrl)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, PaymentStatusActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("status", false);
                    intent.putExtra("transaction_id", mTXNId);
                    intent.putExtra("id", mId);
                    intent.putExtra("isFromOrder", isFromOrder);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                /**
                 * wait 10 seconds to dismiss payu money processing dialog in my case
                 */
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressBarVisibilityPayuChrome(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, 10000);

                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });

        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new PayUJavaScriptInterface(PayUMoneyActivity.this), "PayUMoney");

        /**
         * Mapping Compulsory Key Value Pairs
         */
        Map<String, String> mapParams = new HashMap<>();
        mapParams.put("key", mMerchantKey);
        mapParams.put("txnid", mTXNId);
        mapParams.put("amount", String.valueOf(mAmount));
        mapParams.put("productinfo", mProductInfo);
        mapParams.put("firstname", mFirstName);
        mapParams.put("email", mEmailId);
        mapParams.put("phone", mPhone);
        mapParams.put("surl", mSuccessUrl);
        mapParams.put("furl", mFailedUrl);
        mapParams.put("hash", mHash);
        mapParams.put("service_provider", mServiceProvider);

        webViewClientPost(webView, mAction, mapParams.entrySet());

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Something went wrong, Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Posting Data on PayUMoney Site with Form
 *
 * @param webView
 * @param url
 * @param postData
 */
public void webViewClientPost(WebView webView, String url, Collection<Map.Entry<String, String>> postData) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<html><head></head>");
    sb.append("<body onload='form1.submit()'>");
    sb.append(String.format("<form id='form1' action='%s' method='%s'>", url, "post"));
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : postData) {
        sb.append(String.format("<input name='%s' type='hidden' value='%s' />", item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
    }
    sb.append("</form></body></html>");
    Log.d("TAG", "webViewClientPost called: " + sb.toString());
    webView.loadData(sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
}


/**
 * Hash Key Calculation
 *
 * @param type
 * @param str
 * @return
 */
public String hashCal(String type, String str) {
    byte[] hashSequence = str.getBytes();
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
        algorithm.reset();
        algorithm.update(hashSequence);
        byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();

        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            if (hex.length() == 1)
                hexString.append("0");
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException NSAE) {
    }
    return hexString.toString();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onPressingBack();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    onPressingBack();
}

/**
 * On Pressing Back
 * Giving Alert...
 */
private void onPressingBack() {
    final Intent intent;
    if (isFromOrder)
        intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, ProductInCartList.class);
    else
        intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PayUMoneyActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Warning");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you cancel this transaction?");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}

public class PayUJavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    PayUJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void success(long id, final String paymentId) {

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                mHandler = null;
                Toast.makeText(PayUMoneyActivity.this, "Payment Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

                intent.putExtra("result", "success");

                intent.putExtra("paymentId", paymentId);

                startActivity(intent);

                finish();

            }

        });

    }
}


public void progressBarVisibilityPayuChrome(int visibility) {
    if (getApplicationContext() != null && !isFinishing()) {
        if (visibility == View.GONE || visibility == View.INVISIBLE) {
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
                progressDialog.dismiss();
        } else if (progressDialog == null || !progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog = showProgress(this);
        }
    }
}

public ProgressDialog showProgress(Context context) {
    if (getApplicationContext() != null && !isFinishing()) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final Drawable[] drawables = {getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.l_icon1),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.l_icon2),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.l_icon3),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.l_icon4)
        };

        View layout = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.prog_dialog, null);
        final ImageView imageView;
        imageView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ProgressDialog progDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.ProgressDialog);

        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            int i = -1;

            @Override
            synchronized public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        i++;
                        if (i >= drawables.length) {
                            i = 0;
                        }
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
                        imageView.destroyDrawingCache();
                        imageView.refreshDrawableState();
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawables[i]);
                    }
                });

            }
        }, 0, 500);

        progDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        });
        progDialog.show();
        progDialog.setContentView(layout);
        progDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        return progDialog;
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

prog_dialog.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_progress"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/l_icon1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:text="Processing Your Request"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="normal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Please Wait..."
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

*activity_payumoney.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/r_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/payumoney_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/trans_overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_drawable"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

background_drawable.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#10000000"></solid>
<corners android:radius="0dp" />
```

Comment: Nasir, I tried you code but it didn't even work. Can you please give me a proper test code with your custom activity?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi check your mail

Comment: @NessTyagi Please share code with me thanks in advance

Comment: @NessTyagi PayUJavaScriptInterface  success method never called ??

Comment: @SuryaReddy This code is too old try your logic with PayUMoney sdk. It may be depricate issue.

Answer (score 1):

They have not activated the test account.

Answer (score 1):

"Sorry, some problem occurred" this error comes up when you don't have a valid Merchant key and Salt key. In this case you need to contact PayU Money customer care support team for valid Merchant and Salt key. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

PayUmoney merchant dashboard - at right top you will see "Live Mode" just toggle it to make is "Test Mode".
The Android app integration of PayUmoney is simple. Add these dependency in gradle file

```
    implementation 'com.payumoney.core:payumoney-sdk:7.4.4'
    implementation  'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.4.4'
```

You can find PHP checksum Hash files and android source code [in this reference link](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/payumoney-payment-gateway-integration/).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and am feed up with this integration's.

But after contacting with payumoney.com sport team, they told me that the integration kit showing in the downloading kit is not active, that is the  key(JBZaLc) and salt(GQs7yium) its only a dummy data's. So we need to send your company details including the bank details, then they verify your company details, then they will provide us the new integration kit. With that kit we can do the testing.

Answer (score 0):

Download demo project from here [github project link](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App/releases/tag/s4.3.6c6m1.0.4)

and change

```
int env = PayuConstants.STAGING_ENV;
```

this will do for test mode