# Test url is not working in payumoney

Tags: php, transactions, payment

```
  $MERCHANT_KEY = "JBZaLc";

  $SALT = "GQs7yium";

  $PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://test.payu.in";
```

I have given merchant key, salt & Payumoney base url like i have given above 
but the test url is not working.it transfer to test url gives the error Sorry, Some Problem Occurred.

Comment: Contact the company providing the key.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/81gm63 Is this working now ? I am getting same error.

Comment: Refer this question for answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773892/payumoney-payment-gateway-integration

Answer (score 4):

Leave service provider as blank. That should work.

Comment: service provider is not required for payumoney. that identify by merchant key and merchant salt that is given above by me

Answer (score 3):

```
$MERCHANT_KEY = "gtKFFx";

// Merchant Salt as provided by Payu
$SALT = "eCwWELxi";

// End point - change to https://secure.payu.in for LIVE mode
$PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://test.payu.in";
```

use this if don't work tell me..it's work for me for test account.

Comment: please see the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773892/sorry-some-error-occurred-while-integrating-payumoney-payment-gateway-in-test. we need to create a test account and use its credentials

Comment: This Merchant Key and SALT works fine for Test Server of PayuMoney & Payubiz both. Thanks Bro..