# Payment Gateway Integration Error using PayUMoney in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am using Woocommerce Word press plugin to integrate payment gateway.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

Created my Test Mode account in Pay U Money and recieved key and salt id to configure in the plugin.

After adding product to page in test mode, post view cart when go ahead for checkout, it says thank you ....and then redirect page to https://test.payu.in/_payment with message as "Sorry, Some Problem Occurred."

Comment: This question might be more appropriate at [WordPress Development Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Make  sure your key / salt is right one. refer the http://stackoverflow.com/a/31912971/1533666

Comment: Key and Salt got the right, its been approved from payumoney team.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with payUmoney Test Account key/salt id.

I have tried with Live Mode key and salt id, it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

To
integrate Payumoney in woocommerce "PayU" provides a simple plugin to
integrate. Install it, enter your credential and that’s all.. Done..

If you want to integrate it in wordpress non e-commerce site, it needs customization. Install PHP kit provided by payumoney through FTP or File Manager in hosting control panel.

After that, the
most important thing is you have to pass the values of all required parameter as
mentioned in their documentation. Pass these values with `$_POST`. That’s
it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate your account before you can do a test payment on PayU